# Codeigniter CMS Admin panel?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am planning to build a cms in codeigniter so can anybody help me with the best solution for integrating admin panel according to the mvc pattern ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Stackoverflow is the right platform to explain how to make a CMS system from A to Z in CodeIgniter. I saw this earlier on YouTube. Pretty recent YouTube vids in a collection about how to do this from A to Z.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yROJ84cJORc

Good luck!